# Action payload in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hello i have create a new action files called auth.js , here i have my login function like this :

```
import axios from "axios";

export const LOGIN = "login";


const ROOT_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/jwt/";



export function login(values, callback) {
 const request = axios
.post(`${ROOT_URL}`, values)
.then(() => callback());


return {
 type: LOGIN,
 payload: request


 };
}
```

I would to catch and see my payload how can I do that ? also i want to catch and store the token of my payload to use him for fetch my data with JWT authorization

Answer (score 0):

Do like the following so that the function returns with the object for dispatch with the response from api as the payload and, when the response comes it also calls the callback function with the api response as its parameter,

```
export function login(values, callback) {
 axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}`, values)
  .then((response) => {
    callback(response));
    return { type: LOGIN, payload: response};
   })
}
```